# JNA How to pass struct from Java to C++ method?

Tags: java, jna

I am using JNA for accessing DLL library (C++) methods.

Method I want to access has following signature: `int DownloadData(DateTime dateTime);`

```
Return Values
  COM_ERROR if an error occurs.
  0 if no new records to download.
  # of records transferred, if successful.
```

, DateTime is a structure (C++ code):

```
struct DateTime
{
  int minute;
  int hour;
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
};
```

I am doing in follow way:

```
import com.sun.jna.FunctionMapper;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class JavaApplication1
{
     public static class DateTime extends Structure {
        public int minute;
        public int hour;
        public int day;
        public int month;
        public int year;
     }
```

...

```
     public interface CLibrary extends Library
     {
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("LibPro", CLibrary.class, options);
        int DownloadData(DateTime dateTime);
     }
```

...

```
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
          dateTime.day=1;
          dateTime.hour=0;
          dateTime.minute=0;
          dateTime.month=1;
          dateTime.year=2012;
        System.out.println("Record count : "+CLibrary.INSTANCE.DownloadData(dateTime));
     }
}
```

But my code doesn't return how many record are transferred, but it returns -32704. Library usually returns such a value then something gone wrong.

Am I doing right in JNA terms? What else can I try?

Thanks for help!

**UPD**. If I send null value `CLibrary.INSTANCE.DownloadData(null)` I have the same result

Comment: "my code doesn't return data it should." <-- so, what does it return?

Comment: And how many replies were there supposed to be? I suspect an endianness problem...

Comment: @Andrej fge is onto it here. Inspect the int as bytes in the debugger and my guess is you'll see the issue -32704 is suspicious.

Comment: @fge I didn't understand. Can you explain please?

Comment: -32704 isn't suspicious - hardware returns such a value then something is incorrect

Comment: Your int being returned probably has a difference eanianness. Thus you're seeing -32704 which might very well be the representation of the the number you're expecting with the work endianness: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: I have another function which should return record count based on this data and it returns 0

Comment: For clarification -> the reason I say -32704 is suspicious is because it is very close to (2^8) if, perhaps, the integer returned were unsigned or the wrong endian.

Comment: @Andrej "-32704 isn't suspicious - [...] returns such a value then something is incorrect" <-- you should have told this in the question, how are we supposed to guess? ;)

Comment: There's also a chance the library is returning and unsigned integer. If the value is totally wrong (as in the bits don't make sense either big/little/unsigned) then the problem might be larger. Post the C++ code.

Comment: I don't have C++ code, only DLL and header file

Comment: If your library is using the stdcall calling convention, make sure you extend `StdCallLibrary` instead of `Library`.  It'd also be a good idea to rename your library interface, since you're *not* mapping to the C runtime library.

Comment: @Andrej did you solved this problem, because I'm kinda stuck in it  now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your native method is expecting the structure to be passed by value, you need to declare and pass a parameter that implements `Structure.ByValue`.

Typically you would define an additional class as follows:

```
public class DateTime extends Structure {
    public class ByValue extends DateTime implements Structure.ByValue { }
}
```

Then your mapping declaration looks like this:

```
int DownloadData(DateTime.ByValue dateTime);
```